# Adding CSS to a group of images using Jquery and using this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a 10px outset border to a group of images using jquery.

Current jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("border-outset", "10px");
    });
});
```

I use an alert to test the hover function and it works correctly but when testing the hover for the css properties/attributes mentioned above it does nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `border-outset`  is not an property, replace it with `border-image-outset`

Comment: What Kevin said and also why not just add `img:hover{border-image-outset:10px;}`to your stylesheet?

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, I know I can easily do this with CSS but the point here is to achieve the same output with jQuery.

Comment: Pankaj, I changed the property to border-image-outset in the code but when I run it and hover over the images, still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

just use css:

```
img:hover{
border : solid 10px
}
```

No need for jQuery

```css
img:hover{
border : solid 10px
}
```

```html
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/660852157827166208/G36DKwIS_400x400.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no property called `border-outset`, use `border` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("border", "10px solid");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="//placehold.it/100/" />
<hr />
<img src="//placehold.it/100/" />
```

you can simplify this and just use plain CSS

```css
img:hover {
  border: 10px solid
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/100/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this `border-image-outset` , try and let me know

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("img").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("border-image-outset", "10px");
});
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work, only works with `border-image-source`

Comment: @dippas why? Is it because there is no `border-image-source`? This is not mentioned in question, so assumption is that it is defined in css

Comment: @dippas , heres what you need https://jsfiddle.net/6ycxtyn2/ , this is not the complete answer which i posted, please try to use common sense how `border-image-outset` works

Comment: @AwsmeSandy i'm fully aware that how that works,  you are just assuming thats what OP wants.

Comment: @Morpheus `I am trying to add a 10px outset border to a group of images`, so the element is already `img`, and AFAICT the OP just want `10px outset` not mentioning a `border-image` anywhere

Comment: @dippas atleast i tried to think/assumed and tried to solve it, rather then asking for something els. Its okay, you are right at your place.

Comment: @Morpheus my "assumption" as you call it, it is way closer than this answer's "assumption"

Comment: @dippas same assumption like treating the `border-outset` as `border-image-outset`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that when one `img` is hovered, you want all `img`s to be styled. If so, here is my answer.

`$(this).css("border-outset", "10px");`

`this` Refers to the current `img` that was hovered.

Try this instead:
`$("img").css("border", "10px solid #000");`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").hover(function () {
        $("img").css("border", "10px solid #000");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hover one of the images for all the images to be styled with a black border.</p>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/870425/profile/profile-80.jpg?4">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/870425/profile/profile-80.jpg?4"/>
```

You can replace the CSS with your own, this is just for example.

However, if you only want to style one `img` at a time, you should instead use CSS instead of JS as other answers have mentioned.

Comment: @dippas Yes, but not if you want all the images to be styled when one is hovered. `$(this)` works if you just want one that was hovered to be styled. You should probably use CSS for that instead.

Comment: So I got them to work one at a time using this, I am also trying to make the border disappear when I hover off. Current Code:  $("#vacationimages img").mouseenter(function(){
 
 $(this).css("border", "10px solid #000");
       

});
 
  $("#vacationimages img").mouseout(function(){
 
 $(this).css("border-none");
       

}); //also the background needs to be outset not solid. Thank you.